# In Xcode and SwiftUI how to avoid strings used in Previews being written to Localizable.xcstrings?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, localization, localizable.strings

I have a bunch of custom views. Below is a minimal example:

```swift
struct PairView: View {
    let left: String
    let right: String
    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .firstTextBaseline) {
            Text(left)
                .foregroundColor(.black)
            Text(right)
                .foregroundColor(.gray)
        }
    }
}
```

In application code I write sometimes hardcoded strings, so "1000" and "$" are expected to be written in Localizable.xcstrings automatically by Xcode. This is great!

```swift
PairView(left: "1000", right: "$")
```

However for Previews I have hardcoded strings too but they are dummy text. Not real stuff and I don't want them to be in the Localizable.xcstrings file.

```swift
#Preview {
    PairView(left: "nacho", right: "4d")
}
```

How can I void strings in SwiftUI Previews being written to Localizable.xcstrings?

I read about verbatim (ex: Text(verbatim: "...") stuff but I could not find information on how apply it for custom views.

Comment: I cannot reproduce. The strings you pass to `left` and `right` are not added into the xcstrings file, regardless of whether you put it in a preview.

Comment: If I change `left` and `right` to be of type `LocalizedStringKey`, then it behaves as you want - the strings are added to the xcstrings file when outside `#Preview`, and *not* added to xcstrings when they are inside `#Preview`.

Comment: @Sweeper Thank you for looking at this. You are correct. I was cleaning a project and thought strings were added to xcstrings. This question seems to be not-valid so I will delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `verbatim` parameter in the `Text` initializer. This prevents Xcode from treating these strings as needing localization. However, applying the `verbatim` method directly in custom views might not be straightforward since `verbatim` is an initializer parameter for `Text` views, not a universal feature for all views.

```
struct PreviewText: View {
  var text: String
  
  var body: some View {
    Text(verbatim: text)
  }
}
```

Instructions:

```
#Preview {
  PairView(left: PreviewText(text: "nacho").text, right: PreviewText(text: "4d").text)
}
```